# Is there a way to check if a new application has been deployed recently in glassfish in linux?

Tags: linux, centos7, glassfish

I am not sure if I made it clear.

This is what I want to check.

Say someone deployed a new .ear file few days ago that changed the version of the application. I want to test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I found is to use this command.

```
history | grep "deploy"
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the best way to tell is via server.logs,

`cat server.lo* | grep -B 1 "was successfully deployed"`

```
[2024-01-18T00:10:42.804+0000] [Payara 5.2022.5] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=110 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1705536642804] [levelValue: 800] [[
  HelloWorld-release-2.7.0.1-prod was successfully deployed in 11,927 milliseconds.]]
--
[2024-01-18T00:19:25.424+0000] [Payara 5.2022.5] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=170 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1705537165424] [levelValue: 800] [[
  HelloWorld-release-2.7.1.0-prod was successfully deployed in 6,680 milliseconds.]]
--
[2024-01-18T00:25:42.498+0000] [Payara 5.2022.5] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=83 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1705537542498] [levelValue: 800] [[
  HelloWorld-release-2.7.1.1-prod was successfully deployed in 7,834 milliseconds.]]
--
[2024-01-18T02:44:34.285+0000] [Payara 5.2022.5] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=187 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1705545874285] [levelValue: 800] [[
  HelloWorld-release-2.7.2.0-prod was successfully deployed in 6,535 milliseconds.]]
--
[2024-01-25T13:53:24.681+0000] [Payara 5.2022.5] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=387 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(9)] [timeMillis: 1706190804681] [levelValue: 800] [[
  HelloWorld-release-2.7.3.0-prod was successfully deployed in 6,725 milliseconds.]]
```